# Having Trouble with jQuery Function using .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, for-loop, each

I have a navigation that is made up of Bootstrap dropdowns. Within each dropdown there are 15-20 list-items being generated. I do not have access to the HTML because it's being generated dynamically in a place I can't touch. Due to the number of list-items, I have a requirement to put them into three columns.

I created a jQuery function to count the li's, divide them by 3 and then wrap them in Bootstrap columns. Everything is working perfectly, but I need to fire the same function on each dropdown menu and only count the li's within its respective dropdown menu. Again, I don't have access to the HTML to give each dropdown an ID, but they all have the class "dropdown-menu".

**HTML:**

```
<!-- begin nav -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse yamm">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">IPOG</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-nocollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <!-- Forms -->
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Page Link</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="test">
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Page Link</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Page Link</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Here</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end navbar -->
```

**Working jQuery with ID:**

```
$(function() {

    //Variables
    var n = $("#test li").length,
    x = n / 3,
    lis = $("#test li");

    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=x) {
        lis.slice(i, i+x).wrapAll("<div class='col-xs-4'></div>");
    }

});
```

**Attempt at using each():**

```
$(function() {
    $(".dropdown").each(function() {
        //Variables
        var n = $(".dropdown-menu li").length,
        x = n / 3,
        lis = $(".dropdown-menu li");

        for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=x) {
            lis.slice(i, i+x).wrapAll("<div class='col-xs-4'></div>");
        }
    });
});
```

I think the problem is that my function is counting every li under every .dropdown-menu, instead of counting the li's within the current .dropdown-menu and executing for each one.

**EDIT:** Working Fiddle with corrected logic to handle remainders properly: http://jsfiddle.net/743qLqma/5/

Comment: One additional question re: this solution, with a number not divisible by 3 I'm left with a decimal obviously. The extra li's are being put into the last columns. How can I have them put in the first columns?     

If you look at the fiddle, you will see the final list item being put into the final column in the dropdown. I need it to appear in the first column.

Fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/743qLqma/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/743qLqma/3/)

Comment: I figured out the remainder issue. Updated fiddle to latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `each()` method you should select inner elements like this

```
$(this).find(".dropdown-menu li")
```

instead of

```
$(".dropdown-menu li")
```

this working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bm3wdagy/)

Comment: Consider changing your fiddle link to this one: http://jsfiddle.net/bm3wdagy/1/ (has bootstrap included)

Comment: yes, I've made my changes like it works in ***Working jQuery with ID***

Comment: No, I mean update your answer and change your link to the one I posted... I didn't change any content, only included Bootstrap.css, which you didn't have.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly!

Comment: One additional question re: this solution, with a number not divisible by 3 I'm left with a decimal obviously. The extra li is being put into the last column. How can I have it put in the first column?

Comment: @Jameel what you mean by column ?

Comment: If you look at the fiddle, you will see the final list item being put into the final column in the dropdown. I need it to appear in the first column.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/743qLqma/2/

Comment: Solved. Updated fiddle link in OP.

Comment: @Jameel could yo please vote up for this answer if it's really helped you

Comment: If anyone is interested, the function has been updated in the fiddle at the end of my question to include the logic to properly handle the remainders.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(this) with in the each to access the current dropdown and for example look for its children using $(this).find(....)

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not sure how to implement $(this) in the function.